# Flutter Web Google sign in not working on mobile browsers

Tags: firebase, google-signin, flutter-web

Maybe a very specific edge-case, but I have noticed that my web app is not working on certain mobile devices through a web browser. The code works fine on native mobile-apps and on desktop browsers, but certain mobile browsers aren't working as expected.

Normally when someone attempts to log in, a pop-up opens where the user either selects their account or is logged in silently, but what I have noticed from certain mobile devices is that the pop-up/login process never happens. Is there a way to force the Flutter web app to open the google login through a redirect instead of a popup? Or maybe some other solution that I am not aware of?

Here is my code that I am using:

```
Widget _googleSignInButton() {
    return FlatButton(
      minWidth: 300,
      color: Colors.white60,
      onPressed: () async {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
        await signInWithGoogle().then((user) {
          if (user != null) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, DashboardRoute);
          }
        }).catchError((onError) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        });
      },...
```

```
Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential authResult =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User user = authResult.user;

  // Checking if email and name is null
  assert(user.email != null);
  assert(user.displayName != null);
  assert(user.photoURL != null);
  userID = user.uid;
  newUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
  if (newUser) {
    userData['name'] = user.displayName;
    userData['email'] = user.email;
    userData['photo'] = 'assets/images/userIcon.png';
    await createUser();
  } else {
    await getUserData();
  }

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes up from third-party cookies being disabled, which prevents the .signin() method from opening a new window. This throws a PlatformException, and as far as I know cannot be caught by dart